# What features of the site are available to help make spotting Help Vampires simpler?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-vampire

***TL;DR*** — Apart from manually comparing notes with the [*Identifying Help Vampires*](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) check list, and manually trawling through users' post history, what tools — *if any* — does SO/SE provide for Stackers of a Van Helsing-like nature?

---

***Context***

To solve a problem posed in a question recently, it was necessary for me to ask the asker some questions of my own.

Out of eight or ten such clarifying questions, the asker answered maybe three of them. They even angrily demanded me to stop asking them to clarify their ambiguously-described problem at one point. I recognized the behavior. So I researched the user's question acceptance history. There were a few red flags. There seemed to be a pattern of acknowledging in comments that a proposed solution worked for them, but not accepting the answer.

In the course of researching the user's accept rate, I came across their Meta Stack Exchange profile.  The person in the user's profile picture was made up to look like a character in a horror movie. There was a picture of a person in very intricately-applied, expertly-detailed, film-production-quality make-up. It straight-up looked like a vampire.<sup>*1*</sup>

After trying for three, four days, the asker still hadn't answered the majority of the questions I'd asked them. I invited them to chat so I could try asking again. They blanked me for two more days.

Considering the asker's unhelpful behavior, their ignoring me, their low accept rate track record, them being practically a self-confessed Help Vampire, etc., I decided at that point that I would not be revealing to the asker the working solution I eventually discovered. But I did genuinely want the asker to find a solution to their question. So I persisted with my entreaties for more clarifying details; so that even though the asker wouldn't be getting an answer from me, the information would be there for other SO volunteers to help the asker.

A week earlier, I'd proposed a solution for a different-but-related question the same asker posted. A few days after they  acknowledge the relevancy of my proposed solution for that other related question, they eventually comment in the current question: «*Oh! I figured that related thing out on my own*»; somehow forgetting that I proposed to them several days ago what they are now claiming to have *figured out* on their own.

After I explained the reasons above to the asker as my rationale for bowing out of their bounty, the asker lobbed a few F-bombs at me in the comments. They've been deleted, of course.

That same day, the asker deleted all their comments from their other question. Comments that would have been clear evidence that I'd proposed to them days ago what they now dishonestly claim as: «*I just figured it out on my own*».

Today I noticed that after two years of „*trying to work out*“ whether or not an old answer satisfactorily solved their problem, the asker just today marked a two year old answer as *Accepted*.<sup>*2*</sup> I count that as a positive, though. The asker seems to be turning over a new leaf. Better late than never.

They've also accepted today an answer to another bountied question that was proposed a week ago.<sup>*3*</sup> I think it's fair to say that some kind of impact has been made by certain recent revelations and  turns of events.

***The point***

With all the data SO/SE has at its disposal, it seems like there would be a simpler, more automated way implemented in the SO site itself to make it easier to spot [*Help Vampires*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem). Is there such a feature, and I just haven't found it yet?

---

<sup><sup>*1*</sup></sup>  <sup>*The user has now replaced the vampiric profile pic with a stock SE one. Luckily, I remembered the Wayback Machine at the time.*</sup>
<sup><sup>*2*</sup></sup>  <sup>*The user will very likely delete that comment soon.*</sup>
<sup><sup>*3*</sup></sup>  <sup>*I'm convinced that was done only as a face-saving, damage limitation effort; not because it actually solved the problem. But that's just speculation.*</sup>

Comment: *Out of eight or ten such clarifying questions,* If this is needed, rather than asking for clarification, I'd have just VTC'd as lacking MCVE, or perhaps even as Too Broad (something that needs so many details is unlikely to be sufficiently narrow).

Comment: Isn't the fact that they will, inevitably, get a question ban already solving the problem? Help Vampires tend to post low quality questions, which attract downvotes, and those downvotes across multiple questions, result in question bans. If they aren't asking low quality questions, they're not a true "help vampire", and provided they are on-topic the questions are perfectly valid for the site,

Comment: „*…Isn't…a question ban already solving the problem?…*“ – @Larnu — It may solve ***a*** problem. Namely, it *eventually* reduces the number of people on the site of that bent. And reduces the number of low-quality questions. But that process isn't instantaneous. As somebody volunteering my time to answer questions and provide free content to SO/SE, what I see as ***the*** problem is people of an ungrateful, disrespectful nature wasting my time. The point of my question is to learn of ways I may not know about that would save me from wasting my time. That's not a problem of question quality.

Comment: If a question/comment/answer is disrespectful, flag it @deduper . If it's low quality, down vote, vote to close, move on. You waste little time then.

Comment: „*…If it's low quality, down vote, vote to close, move on…*“ – @Larnu — Unlike the majority of SO users, gamification, downvotes and upvotes don't have the same value to me. Though it may not be intended to be used as such, I use SO as an educational resource. A „*low quality*“ question ***to you***, may have significant educational value ***to me***. As did the question I refer to above. Unlike your comment — *for which I am grateful, btw* — my meta question isn't about question quality. It's about not wasting my time. Even „*high quality*“ question-askers can be time wasters too. You know?

Comment: Votes aren't about "gamification", @deduper , they are about letting other members of the community (which includes the OP) know that the question/answer is useful and or helpful. If it's not helpful or useful then it receives downvotes, and it receives upvotes if it is. If you are "worried" about wasting time from reading questions from "time wasters" then perhaps ensure you only read questions that have (several) upvotes and from someone with more than a couple hundred reputation; so that you know that other members of the community know the question is useful.

Comment: Let the community do "the work" for you, and inform you what posts you should spend your time on; or more importantly to you what posts you shouldn't.

Comment: The effort is commendable (to ultimately recruit a long-term contributor), but the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) event happened [10 years ago on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/). Perhaps consider optimising for the 99.99% of all use cases ([hits from](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) [search engines](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178/highest-view-rate-questions-in-a-particular-tag-non-community-wiki))?

Comment: For instance, a lot of questions are missing comprehensive answers (the existing answers are merely hints - as if Stack Overflow is some kind of school where the full answer is deliberately hidden -, or are otherwise incomplete), answers are out of date, are not of publication quality, etc.

Answer (score 12):

I don't see much need for such a feature. We're not doing that user wise, but based on question contents quality. If the quality doesn't fit, downvote, closevote and move on, that's it.

If the user will reach a certain limit of not so well received questions, they'll be question banned automatically, deleted questions still count against them.

> That same day, the asker deleted all their comments from their other question. Comments that would have been clear evidence that I'd proposed to them days ago what they now dishonestly claim as: *«I just figured it out on my own»*.

Well, that's probably not honest by that user, but why should we care?
If their question is doomed, all of that will vanish anyways.

Comments are 2nd class citizens in the Stack Exchange ecosystem, and so are comments which may help a user.
Answers are a different thing, if they are present and upvoted, they'll stay, and not be deleted automatically. Thus such a user cannot try to *"hide"* their behavior, and probably attract even more downvotes to their question.

---

> ***The point***
>
> With all the data SO/SE has at its disposal, it seems like there would be a simpler, more automated way implemented in the SO site itself to make it easier to spot Help Vampires. Is there such a feature, and I just haven't found it yet?

As mentioned in 1st place, this feature already exists, and is called *question (answer) ban*.
It's automatically applied to users, which repeatedly post bad, not well received content.

#### Hence it's important to downvote, and flagging questions for closure.

As your story evolves about your time wasted in comments So don't wait too long for an appropriate reply, leave the unconstructive discussion, and do as I mentioned in bold above.
Users which try to do this repeatedly will be detected by the system, and get banned. It's quite hard for them to get out of the ban (especially if they have deleted questions), and the ban is unlimited in time. You can read in more detail, what it needs to lift that ban in this Q&A from the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq):

- [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: Isn't answer ban also a thing? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @10Rep Answers by _help vampires_?? Mistakenly _I have the same problem_ answers maybe. These will be also destroyed by NAA flags, and due to answer bans blocking help vampires, who are trying it that way round, yes.

Comment: „*…on question contents quality…the quality doesn't fit, downvote, closevote and move on…*“ –  @πάνταῥεῖ — Unlike yourself and the majority of your users, gamification, downvotes and upvotes don't have the same value to me. Though you may not intend for it to be used as such, I use SO as an educational resource. A „*low value*“ question ***to you***, may have significant educational value ***to me***. As did the question I refer to above. Unlike your answer, my question isn't about question quality. It's about not wasting my time. Your „*high quality*“ question-askers can be time wasters too.

Comment: Although I speak for πάντα ῥεῖ, I feel I've seen enough of their answers to suggest they too don't see votes as a "game" either, @deduper . Someone who did would certainly not post this answer.

Comment: @deduper I don't get your comments relevance here? Were your comments good enough to answer? So these should have been posted as an answer. If not, you shouldn't care. We're all waste our time here sometimes (see my avatar picture). If I have a smell of something, I often even don't care to ask the OP for clarification, but downvote the quesiton, and close vote for _needs more focus_, or _needs details_.

Comment: @deduper In your post, you said you had to ask them 8-10 clarifying questions and they only answered a few of them. How can that possibly be considered a high-quality question? Maybe you *personally* found it interesting despite that, but it clearly isn't good for *the site*.

Comment: @deduper "I use SO as an educational resource." - which is fine, but why you see problem with users not answering your comments or your comments being deleted then? You got *your* educational value out of your comments - what else you are looking for? If *you* don't get educational value from your comments just don't make them...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: „*…or **your comments** being deleted then*?…*“ — deduper: „*the **asker** deleted all **their comments** from their other question…*“

Comment: @deduper Please see the updates at my answer. I hope that makes it chrystal clear, why we don't need a new feature, to handle such situation, and what the course of action should be.

Comment: „*How can that possibly be considered a high-quality question?*“ – @JohnMontgomery — I'll concede, for the majority of its existence that Q could not be considered „*high quality*“. It had 0 votes and 0 answers. However, a case could be made that, precisely because of my tenacity, educational curiosity and desire to help, that Q has now been transformed into an extraordinarily well-specified one; with not one, but ***two*** MREs, 4 upvotes (*net gain of 2*) and finally receiving its first answer today — *its 20th day* — the day its bounty expires. What quality rating would ***you*** give it?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, although you read my Q incorrectly, your reply nudged me to do what  I've been considering doing all along: Stop engaging with ***all*** SO users completely. For my use case — *honing my skills/learning new skills* — I don't really ***need*** to engage with SO users. I could achieve my goals offline. Take SO users, SO's gamification, upvotes/downvotes out of the equation. Stop volunteering my valuable time to entitled ingrates. Stop giving SO/SE free content and editing services. I'll ***consume*** SO content purely as a training resource; as coding katas. That'll work for me!

Answer (score 5):

If someone has a lot of poorly received questions, they'll eventually get question-banned. If you notice someone that you believe is a Help Vampire but has not been question-banned, you should flag one of their posts for moderator intervention explaining the situation.

If someone persists in refusing to clarify their question, you should flag for closure, downvote, disengage, and move on. You could also post a `cv-pls` request for the question in [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/). Either way, it's really not worth arguing with an OP who won't clarify the question - their question can be closed until such time as they see fit to give the necessary clarifications.

If someone is swearing or otherwise being abusive in comments, flag the comments as Harassment, Bigotry, or Abuse. If they contain profanity, they'll likely be auto-removed by the flag, but if not you can also post a `flag-pls` request in SOCVR for the rude comments.

I'm not sure what the profile picture of the user in question has to do with anything - merely setting your profile picture to be a vampire doesn't prove that you yourself are a help vampire any more than hanging out in a garage makes you a car.